# Facebook log in vs regular log in, mongo schema issue

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql, schema, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using `mongo db` to store user data, their passwords. I have two ways of creating an account:

1. Regular sign up when user selects `username` and `password` and
2. Sign up using `facebook` log in.

Now, when I have regular sign up, `password` and `username` should be required, but using `facebook` log in they are not, so I am wondering how I should now design a schema for the `users` model to include both cases?

The most obvious way seems like to have two different models: `users_facebook` and `users_regular`, but is it the right way to go? Why or why not? It could also be `users_auth` (auth data only for users who signed up manually) and `users_data` (both users' types data). There is also something like `MongoDB Facebook Stitch` that is somehow used for the purpose it seems, although I do not get what it is. I am very new to databases and not sure which is the right way to go. The problem seems though pretty trivial.

Comment: I would suggest you let facebook users return back to the signup page and enter a password. Relying on a third party api to store user info is not a good idea.You can extract the email from the fb api. This way if you decide to add another authentication api you can do with ease.

Comment: But there is no sense in using facebook log in then

Comment: I understand, if you're targeting only the facebook users, then why would you use regular signup ? what i'm saying is an application should not rely heavily on third party services, specially in the case of authentication. If facebook had a server outage for a long period of time, or for some reason your facebook app fails to work, or was blocked your users will never be able to login to your application. You might be implementing a very bad user journey.

Comment: It is a common practice nowadays: allow user to either log in through facebook or allow regular sign up. Not everyone has facebook, so I can not rely only on it. On the other hand some users who have Facebook account would be able to sign up very fast: that is good because many users are just drawn away from using a service that requires fields to fill up.

Comment: I understand the ease of logging in for users with just social connect buttons. But still you should also give the priority to regular signup. For social login process allow the user to enter a password, the rest of the form fields could be auto filled using the social network api.